# Xamarin Android - Portable Shared Library Code runs Incredibly Slowly

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, garbage-collection, xamarin.android

I am trying to create an application with Xamarin. I have a portable shared library with some code which takes a while to process. I've created a console app which uses this library, and I'm also working on an Android app which uses the same portable shared library with Xamarin.Android, however the shared portable code runs incredibly slowly on Android.

EDIT: I also tried putting my code in a shared project, not a shared library to see if it would run at a normal speed, but it didn't help.

I timed some methods with stopwatches like so:

**Original**

```
return p => p.EndsWith(endingString)
```

**With Stopwatch**

```
return (p =>
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    bool ans = p.EndsWith(endingString);
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
    return ans;
});
```

The Android application is really slow for some reason. The code above told me that just to check whether a string ends with something took approx 1411 ticks on Android whereas on my computer it took only 5 ticks, meaning the Android version took 280x more ticks on Android.

Another method took 243669 ticks on Android and 4561 ticks on my computer, meaning it took 53x as many ticks.

The method below took 19847785 ticks on Android and 819619 on my computer, being 24 times slower. I don't think the slowness is caused by my code particular, but I wanted to provide an example of some of my code, just in case it's caused by something in my code.

```
private void InitialiseFrequencyDictionary()
{
    if (_frequencyDictionary != null) return;
    StreamReader streamReader = EmbeddedResourceGetter.GetFrequencyListStreamReader();
    _frequencyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string line;

    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line = streamReader.ReadLine()))
    {
        try
        {
            string[] lineSplit = line.Split(new[] {' '}, 2);
            _frequencyDictionary.Add(lineSplit[0], lineSplit[1]);
        }
        catch { /* ignored */ }
    }
}
```

The whole classes's public method as a whole took 155524065 ticks on Android and took 15761ms. It took 2471652 ticks and 1152ms on my computer, meaning it took 63x as many ticks and 15x longer on Android than on my computer.

I know these results are not completely accurate as I am testing them on different devices, different OS's and different architectures, but I don't feel like these accurately represent the difference in performance between my computer and my phone whatsoever. My phone scores 1219 and 4273 in Geekbench, in the single core and multicore scores respectively, and my computer scores 3288 and 6978 on Geekbench. This means my phone should be at most 3x slower than my computer, not 16x!

Whenever this code is executing on my Android device, I get a lot of messages from the Garbage Collector (I think) in the Output section of Visual Studio.

```
01-08 18:48:27.527 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 0.90ms, total 1.08ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 880K major 880K los 8K
01-08 18:48:30.133 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 23 num_hash_entries 29 sccs size 29 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.09ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.03ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:30.133 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 0.85ms, total 0.98ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 880K major 880K los 8K
01-08 18:48:32.760 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 23 num_hash_entries 29 sccs size 29 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.09ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.03ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:32.760 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 1.81ms, total 2.06ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 896K major 896K los 8K
01-08 18:48:35.034 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 23 num_hash_entries 29 sccs size 29 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.09ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.03ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:35.034 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 1.19ms, total 1.37ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 912K major 912K los 8K
01-08 18:48:37.687 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 23 num_hash_entries 29 sccs size 29 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.09ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.03ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:37.687 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 0.59ms, total 1.61ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 912K major 912K los 8K
01-08 18:48:39.298 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 23 num_hash_entries 29 sccs size 29 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.09ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.03ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:39.298 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 4.78ms, total 5.13ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 1248K major 1248K los 296K
01-08 18:48:39.378 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 23 num_hash_entries 29 sccs size 29 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.09ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.03ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:39.378 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 7.58ms, total 7.81ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 2336K major 2336K los 1348K
01-08 18:48:39.459 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 23 num_hash_entries 29 sccs size 29 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.09ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.03ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:39.459 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 7.24ms, total 7.46ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 3488K major 3488K los 2821K
01-08 18:48:39.536 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 23 num_hash_entries 29 sccs size 29 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.09ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.03ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:39.536 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 6.13ms, total 6.40ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 4624K major 4624K los 2821K
01-08 18:48:39.627 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 23 num_hash_entries 29 sccs size 29 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.09ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.03ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:39.627 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 8.29ms, total 8.51ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 5776K major 5776K los 5877K
01-08 18:48:39.705 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 23 num_hash_entries 29 sccs size 29 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.09ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.03ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:39.705 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 6.47ms, total 6.68ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 6832K major 6832K los 5877K
01-08 18:48:39.796 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 23 num_hash_entries 29 sccs size 29 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.09ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.03ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:39.796 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 15.16ms, total 16.35ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 7888K major 7888K los 5877K
01-08 18:48:39.876 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 23 num_hash_entries 29 sccs size 29 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.00ms dfs2 0.09ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.03ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:39.876 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 5.47ms, total 5.68ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 8928K major 8928K los 5877K
01-08 18:48:40.031 I/art     ( 9357): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6197(237KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 45% free, 4MB/8MB, paused 1.286ms total 18.093ms
01-08 18:48:40.032 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.06ms sort 0.01ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 7/7/7/1 dfs passes 52/31
01-08 18:48:40.032 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MAJOR: (Minor allowance) pause 33.66ms, total 36.59ms, bridge 0.00ms major 9968K/0K los 8789K/0K
01-08 18:48:40.110 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.06ms sort 0.01ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:40.110 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 5.65ms, total 5.88ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 11008K major 11008K los 8789K
01-08 18:48:40.190 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.06ms sort 0.01ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:40.190 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 6.16ms, total 6.37ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 12032K major 12032K los 8789K
01-08 18:48:40.283 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.06ms sort 0.01ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:40.283 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 14.61ms, total 17.42ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 13104K major 13104K los 8789K
01-08 18:48:40.373 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.06ms sort 0.01ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:40.373 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 5.86ms, total 6.18ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 14144K major 14144K los 8789K
01-08 18:48:40.455 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.06ms sort 0.01ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:40.455 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 5.82ms, total 6.05ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 15168K major 15168K los 8789K
01-08 18:48:40.536 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.06ms sort 0.01ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:40.536 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 5.51ms, total 5.72ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 16224K major 16224K los 8789K
01-08 18:48:40.772 I/art     ( 9357): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 338(11KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 45% free, 4MB/8MB, paused 838us total 17.067ms
01-08 18:48:40.772 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.02ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 7/7/7/1 dfs passes 52/31
01-08 18:48:40.773 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MAJOR: (Minor allowance) pause 74.78ms, total 78.16ms, bridge 0.00ms major 17264K/0K los 18218K/0K
01-08 18:48:40.850 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.02ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:40.850 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 5.58ms, total 5.81ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 18304K major 18304K los 18218K
01-08 18:48:40.929 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.02ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:40.929 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 5.98ms, total 6.53ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 19344K major 19344K los 18218K
01-08 18:48:41.008 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.02ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:41.008 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 5.53ms, total 5.74ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 20400K major 20400K los 18218K
01-08 18:48:41.089 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.02ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:41.089 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 7.68ms, total 7.74ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 21440K major 21440K los 18230K
01-08 18:48:41.168 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.02ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:41.168 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 5.56ms, total 5.77ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 22496K major 22496K los 18230K
01-08 18:48:41.247 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 21 num_hash_entries 24 sccs size 24 init 0.00ms df1 0.05ms sort 0.02ms dfs2 0.06ms setup-cb 0.01ms free-data 0.02ms links 0/0/0/0 dfs passes 0/0
01-08 18:48:41.247 D/Mono    ( 9357): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 5.64ms, total 6.09ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 23520K major 23520K los 18230K
```

So **is this slowness normal for Xamarin? Is this a bug in Xamarin, or is there something I'm missing? Is this something caused by the garbage collector?**

Comment: This code is depending on File IO and Mememory speed. Not CPU speed. Can you maybe provide a sample data set so I can see if I can do the loading faster? I have some ideas I would like to test out.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I'm using the 2012 english version of this: https://invokeit.wordpress.com/frequency-word-lists/

I don't think the slowness is caused by any of my code in particular though, because the shared code runs slow all over. It even takes unusually long to run `return p.EndsWith("some string");`!

Comment: Thanks will have a look. Will let you know what I find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have investigated a bit more. This issue is not only there when using a PCL but also when having the word list in Android Assets.

First I tried something like this:

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<string, int>> ReadWordFrequenciesAsync(Stream stream)
{
    var freqs = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) != null)
        {
            var split = line.Split(' ');
            var word = split[0];
            var frequency = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(split[1], out frequency))
                freqs.Add(word, frequency);

            line = null;
        }
    }

    return freqs;
}

public static Stream GetWordListFromPcl()
{
    var assembly = typeof(WordListReader).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WordList.Content.en.txt");
}
```

This took 54 ms on my PC and around 8 more seconds on my Nexus 5.

Modifying the code to not parse the frequency to an int like so:

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> ReadWordFrequenciesAsync(Stream stream = null)
{
    var freqs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) != null)
        {
            var split = line.Split(' ');
            var word = split[0];
            var frequency = split[1];
            freqs.Add(word, frequency);

            line = null;
        }
    }

    return freqs;
}
```

This made the code 2 seconds faster on the Nexus 5.

I tried the same just from Android assets where I read the stream like:

```
var stream = Assets.Open("en.txt");
```

This resulted in identical read times. This means that the PCL is not at fault.

One last thing I tried was to read the entire file into memory. Like so:

```
public static async Task<string> ReadWordFrequenciesStringAsync(Stream stream = null)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

This takes less than a second!

OK, so what is the conclusion? I think the `line.Split` method is the one at fault! What can we do instead?

We can try implement our own splitter. Tried something like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static Tuple<string, string> MySplit(this string s, char c)
    {
        var l = s.Length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] == c)
            {
                return new Tuple<string, string>(s.Substring(0, i), s.Substring(i + 1));
            }
        }

        return null;
    } 
}
```

This saved a whole second, while still parsing the frequency value to an int. The performance of `MySplit` is the same if we use `string[]` as return value instead so not much to gain there.

Using unsafe code might help on performance here. But the time is actually not reading the file, but parsing it.

Comment: > OK, so what is the conclusion? I think the line.Split method is the one at fault! What can we do instead?

No. The problem is due to VM transitions. `Assets.Open()` returns a `Stream` which wraps a Java type, so reading it involves lots of VM transitions. `.ReadToEnd()` *reduces* those transitions, speeding things up.

Comment: @jonp alright, thanks. The performance with `Assets.Open()` and Reading a Manifest Resource in the PCL was more or less the same when reading the file. Although splitting it and converting the string to an int piled up a lot of time. However, will have another look later.